# How to plot edge weights in igraph python

Tags: python, plot, igraph

How to show edge weights in the plot in igraph. I am not able to find any documentation for showing weights in igraph python module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding edge weights as labels to them is turned out to be the solution. Just add

```
g.es["label"] = weights
```

Comment: Yeah, but how can you plot this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using matplotlib to plot, you can add `edge_label` parameter with the computed weights.

```
igraph.plot(g, layout = 'auto', edge_label = weights)
```

Then the weights should show up on the plot.